# config xampp for nodejs

Tags: node.js

Why do I see the following page on the Apache Web Server

Displays the code of the page?

```
http://localhost/main.js
```

I install [Windows Installer](http://nodejs.org/#download).

I'm running all the code written in the Command Prompt
But this code can not see inside the browser

In other words,

How do I run nodejs code in a browser ?

---

update,

My Code :

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    });
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Comment: hey, i think i also need apache to handle the virtualhost too....

Answer (score 0):

First off.. Apache has nothing to do with node.

Start the main.js file by running `node main.js` and then navigate to where the node server is running (presuming main.js actually creates a web server). Check the port and hostname in main.js. Should be something like: `http://localhost:8000`

Comment: I'd stop the apache web server,
Then I copied main.js desktop,
Then I opened a Command Prompt and run main.js,
I saw this message in cmd
__Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/__
Then I typed in the browser url http://127.0.0.1:1337
Nothing happened!!!!
What is my issue?